# How Can I SELECT query with CASE condition and SUM()

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table structure
[image]

I'm currently using these sql statements. My table has the field trx_type which contains "LD" or "LP". I can sum up the amount of principal by executing 2 SQL statements as shown below.

```
select sum(principal) from loanhist where trx_type ='LD' and ac_no  = '101300' and cycle = 1  --150000
select sum(principal) from loanhist where trx_type ='LP' and ac_no  = '101300' and cycle = 1--- 73512.13
```

Which if I subtract LD from LP I get `76,487.87`

When I tried to use CASE condition this way:

```
-SUM(CASE WHEN trx_type='LD' THEN LoanHist.principal ELSE 0 END) -
SUM(CASE WHEN trx_type='LP' THEN LoanHist.principal ELSE 0 END) AS outstanding_balance
```

I got this `-229,463.61`.

Since LD has a negative sign, if I should remove the negative sign from SUM it adds the digits instead of subtracting.

Can someone please suggest a better way of solving this!!

Comment: Please provide sample data. I'm not clear what result you are trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ABS()` to get the absolute (positive) value for the sake of making your subtraction simple:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN trx_type='LD' THEN ABS(LoanHist.principal) ELSE 0 END)
```